# C++ - How to use memmove for items in 2D array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memmove

I have the following 2D array:

```
float accumulator[MAX_CHANNELS][2*MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
```

and I keep moving the blocks of memory in my code for every channel like this:

```
for (int channel = 0; channel < nChannels; channel++) {
    memmove(accumulator[channel], accumulator[channel] + stepSize, fftFrameSize * 2 * sizeof(float));
}
```

However, this gives me wrong results and I don't understand why. What is wrong with the `memmove` call that I am using?

Alternatively, I tried using the following 1D arrays (1 for each channel)  instead and got correct results:

```
float accumulator1[2*MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
float accumulator2[2*MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];

memmove(accumulator1, accumulator1 + stepSize, fftFrameSize * 2 * sizeof(float));
memmove(accumulator2, accumulator2 + stepSize, fftFrameSize * 2 * sizeof(float));
```

Comment: What does wrong results mean? We need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In the second piece of code, you're using 2 arrays.  In the first piece of code, we have no idea what `MAX_CHANNELS` is, or what `nChannels` is.  So the two are not equivalent unless you hard-coded `2` for `MAXCHANNELS` and `nChannels`.

Comment: What `stepSize` and `fftFrameSize` causes the error? Also what is `MAX_FRAME_LENGTH` equal to?

Comment: Why are you moving the data instead of just moving the index  of which row is most recent?

Answer (score 0):

I have not undertaken any coding for several years, but it looks to me that possibly you have written code that is difficult to follow logically.

My only suggesting is to find pen and paper draw a line horizontally through the middle of the paper so that you have two sections, representing each block of memory you want to move. Make the bottom half of the paper to represent the SOURCE and the top half to represent the DESTINATION. Write the letters A, B and C in the top half vertically down the side. Then write the numbers 1, 2 and 3 vertically down the side of the bottom half.

Then on a separate piece of paper write down the the name of the counter "channel" start it with value zero.

Now cross out the letter A from the destination and put the number 1 in it place = number 1 goes from source to destination overwriting A in destination. Now increment the counter "channel" by 1 on the separate piece of paper. Repeat 2 more times this whole operation. Now see what's in destination and what's left in source and the value of the counter "channel" this will show you what is going on inside your computers memory and the counter "channel". Personally would be inclined to rewrite the code so that the memmove second parameter was not also named channel. Inside the square brackets. Hope this helps. Here is the function explained http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/.
Don't forget that the memmove function will continue so long as channel is < nchannels. You need to write out the values in all variables during the loop, standard practice for debugging.